# Implementing a login in django

Tags: django, django-authentication

In my `base.html` I placed this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
you are logged in!
{% else %}
<h3>Login</h3>
<form action="/login/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" />
<label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" />
<p><input type="submit" value="Login →"></p>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

In `urls.py`:

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
```

When I accessed `/login` I had to make a `login.html` file. I created `templates/registration/login.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username/pass didnt match</p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm not seeing the username/pass, but I'm still seeing the  meaning my user is not authenticated yet.

Btw, I don't have the CSRF middleware loaded. Did I miss a step or two?

One other thing, I accessed `logout.html` and it went into my django admin logout page. I tried making a `templates/registration/logout.html` but it didn't override that part. Hrm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh. Apparently my actual template had `action="/login"` but when I typed it in the example here it had an end slash, I re-added the end slash and that was it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing the `user` variable to your template context? Either explicitly, or via a context processor?

Comment: I'm not passing the `user` variable explicitly but I don't get any warnings that there is no `user` object so I assume it's getting passed through some means.

Comment: Django templates don't warn if a template isn't present, they just fail silently. So if you're not passing it (or, as I say, using the context processor), it's not there. Try just outputting the value of `{{ user }}` to see for sure.